# Simple custom register/login system how to hash and retrieve password

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a simple register/login system and right now when the user registers it just stores their plain password in the database. I am wondering how I can hash it then when they login, how do I unhash it and compare it to what they put in.

All I have in my users table/model class is username and password

## UsersController

```
// GET: Register User
public ActionResult Register(User user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (UserContext db = new UserContext())
        {
            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        ModelState.Clear();
    }
    return View();
}

// POST: Login User
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(User user)
{
    using (UserContext db = new UserContext())
    {
        var usr = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username == user.Username && u.Password == user.Password);
        if (usr != null)
        {
            Session["UserID"] = usr.Username.ToString();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Profile");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or Password Incorrect");
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: You cant 'unhash' a hashed password (its a one way algorithm). To compare, you run the same algorithm on the login password and then compare it with the value you stored in the Register method.

Comment: As @StephenMuecke said, you can't unhash a hashed string. You could use asp.net identity if you want to provide login mechanism in your app. You can check on the [asp.net identity site](http://www.asp.net/identity)